# T-SQL query (analyze consecutive rows in a table based on specific criteria)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in a SQL Server 2016 database:

```
      Time                  Identifier  Category
1.    2821-01-04 17:41.0    1002        A1001
2.    2821-01-05 17:41.0    1002        A1001
3.    2821-01-06 17:42.0    1001        A1001
4.    2821-01-07 17:44.0    1002        A1001
5.    2821-01-08 17:44.0    1002        A1001
6.    2821-01-09 17:44.0    1002        A1001
7.    2821-01-10 17:44.0    1002        A1001
8.    2821-01-11 17:44.0    1002        A1001
9.    2821-01-12 17:44.0    1002        A1001
10.   2821-01-13 17:44.0    1002        A1001
11.   2821-01-14 17:45.0    1001        A1001
12.   2821-01-15 17:46.0    1002        A1001
13.   2821-01-16 17:46.0    1002        A1001
14.   2821-01-17 17:46.0    1002        A1001
15.   2821-01-18 17:46.0    1002        A1001
16.   2821-01-19 17:46.0    1002        A1001
17.   2821-01-20 17:46.0    1002        B1001
18.   2821-01-21 17:46.0    1002        B1001
19.   2821-01-22 17:46.0    1002        B1001
20.   2821-01-23 17:46.0    1001        B1001
21.   2821-01-24 17:48.0    1002        B1001
22.   2821-01-25 17:48.0    1002        B1001
23.   2821-01-26 17:48.0    1002        B1001
24.   2821-01-27 17:48.0    1002        B1001
25.   2821-01-28 17:48.0    1001        B1001
26.   2821-01-29 17:52.0    1002        B1001
27.   2821-01-30 17:52.0    1002        B1001
28.   2821-01-31 17:52.0    1002        B1001
29.   2821-02-01 17:52.0    1002        B1001
```

What I need is an SQL query that gets the time difference between any 2 *consecutive* rows, first being [Identifier] = 1001 and second being [Identifier] = 1002, for each [Category] (i.e. calculation should be done only for the same category).
Consecutive pair of records to be considered are: records [3,4] and [11,12] and [20,21] and [25,26]. First [identifier] is 1001 and consecutive [identifier] is 1002, consider this a pair.
Therefore we need first to identify these pairs. Only pairs within the same [Category] are relevant. Pairs that belong to different categories should be ignored.

I need to know how many times the difference between these pairs is 1 sec, 2 sec, 2 sec.... up to 5 seconds.

Desired output:

```
Num of seconds  Category    Count
1               A1001       1
2               A1001       1
3               A1001       0
4               A1001       0
5               A1001       0
1               B1001       0
2               B1001       1
3               B1001       0
4               B1001       1
5               B1001       0
```

Comment: It's helpful if you provide sample data in a consumable form, e.g. a declaration of a table variable and insert the data. What have you tried? What didn't work? What order is "consecutive"? Could you show how the rules apply to your sample data, e.g. the first two rows are ignored because they do not start from `Identifier = 1001`?

Comment: Not clear on identifier versus category

Comment: Edited and added more details to clarify. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like the following will get you in the ballpark.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [time],
            [identifier],
            [category],
            CASE WHEN identifier = 1001 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, [time], LEAD([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY [time], identifier)) END as TimeDiff
        FROM yourtable
    )timesub
WHERE identifier = 1001
ORDER BY category, TimeDiff
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill,  however... you are considering only [Identifier']=1001, not sure why [Identifier]=1002 does not appear in the query. We must identify a pair of consecutive 1001/1002

Comment: @User123 it is considered in the subquery. The `LEAD()` window function takes the NEXT row when ordered by that `ORDER BY` and performs the date math then with `DATEDIFF()`. In the end though, only the `1001` records are needed since those are the ones in which this math's result will reside. Essentially "If this record is 1001, then look at the next record when ordered by time (for this category) and subtract this record from what is found in the next record... if this is a 1002 record then don't bother with the math". Later on we just keep the 1001 record that contains the results.

Comment: Thank you so much JNevill, I am very impressed. Amazingly simple solution using LEAD() function! Small change: can you please edit the answer and replace ORDER BY [time] ASC with ORDER BY [time],[category],[identifier] ASC

Comment: There's no need to order by Category as we are already partitioning by it (the records being ordered in this window are all of the same category). Also because your times appear to be distinct ordering by the `identifier` is probably superfluous, although if you have records where a 1001 and 1002 occur at the same timestamp, then that would make sense. I will add that into the ORDER BY clause of the Lead() window function.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I have records where 1001 and 1002 have the same timestamp. I tested the modified query on a very large data set (millions of records) and it works correctly. However, the original query that orders by [time] only, returns in some cases incorrect results.

Comment: Perfect. That makes absolute sense. I have updated the answer to reflect that change. I'm excited that it's doing what you want!